# Javascript weird behaviour of if block

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

While declaring function in javascript I come across this weird behaviour. I am not able to understand the reason. Can anyone explain.

```
if ( true ) {
    function myFun() {
        alert( "true block" );
    }
} else {
    function myFun() {
        alert( "false block" );
    }
}
myFun();
```

It's showing alert of false block!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about javascript hoisting

variable declarations and function declarations are hoisted to the beginning of the current scope in javascript.

This is better understood by,

```
/*hoisting will make the definitions look like this*/
function myfunc() { x = 10; } <------
                                    |
function myfunc() { x = 20; } <-----|---- 
                                    |   |
if(true){                           |   |
  function myfunc() {x = 10;} -------   |
}                                       |
else{                                   |
  function myfunc() {x = 20;} -----------
}

myfunc();
alert(x);
```

the alert will always fire 20. as the 2nd definition overrides the first.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `myFun` function is hoisted. You should *never* declare a function like this in an if-statement. Check whether some variable is `true` within the function, instead.

Hoisting: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Answer (score 0):

There is no block level scope in Javascript. All variables declared in if block is actually hoisted.
So, when you write your if else, the actual function variable, `myFun` got overwritten in else block and is hoisted.

Answer (score 0):

in Scoping and Hoisting process your function myFun is overwritten , so to avoid this behaviour try this

```
var myFun;
if ( true ) {
   myFun= function(){
        alert( "true block" );
    }
} else {
   myFun = function() {
        alert( "false block" );
    }
}
myFun();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically assign myFun you shoudl use the following syntax

```
if (true) {
    myFun=function(){alert('true');}
}else{
    myFun=function(){alert('false');}
}
myFun();
```

Because if you are using the `function MyFun()` declaration style, the function are defined at parsing time, rather than runtimr like you desire.